# How to adjust ggplot with facet to just show one or two variables per Plot view

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr, boxplot, facet

I am having trouble to adjust a boxplot for numerical variables
using ggplot, I would like to adjust the console Plot view
to just show one or two variables at time.

Here's the code I am using:

```
##################################################################################
#                              Data                                              #
#                                                                                #
##################################################################################

data("diamonds")
basePlot <- diamonds[ names(diamonds)[!names(diamonds) %in% c("color", "clarity")] ]

##################################################################################

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer

ggplot(pivot_longer(basePlot, -cut, names_to="var", values_to="val"),
       aes(cut, val, color=cut)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="black", outlier.shape=16, outlier.size=1, notch=FALSE) +
  xlab("Diamond Cut") +
  facet_wrap(~var, nrow=2, scales="free") +
  scale_x_discrete(guide=guide_axis(n.dodge=2))
```

Console Output:

[image]

Expected Output consist in just one or two variables per view,

An example could be just carat and depth in one view,
Price and table in the other,
and so on...

Comment: Probably similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59957340/9022665

Comment: these are boxplots...

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `facet_wrap_paginate` from the [ggforce](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggforce/man/facet_wrap_paginate.html) package?

Comment: @Z.Lin, yess!, `p + facet_wrap_paginate(~var, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, page = 1)`  shows me one varible per view, but does not work for every var as I expected, as just one variable is shown in the view, the others are ignored and no plot is genereted for them... is there anyway to adjust it?

Comment: Usually it's used in a for-loop. [This](https://www.programmingwithr.com/how-to-make-your-facet-wrap-facet-grid-ggplots-span-across-multiple-pages-in-pdf/) may help (though I think the author forgot to close off  the for-loop's curly bracket in the code...)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!, thank you so much @Z.Lin!!!